# Write-Output -InputObject (,'Test') -NoEnumerate

Tags: windows, powershell, switch-statement, enumerate

I think this is a bug that only applies to PowerShell Windows 5.1:

The `-NoEnumerate` switch doesn't work when the input is provided via the named `-InputObject` argument:

The following function returns `False`:

```
Function Test {Write-Output -InputObject (,'Foo') -NoEnumerate} 
(Test) -is [Array]
```

While this functiin returns `True`:

```
Function Test {Write-Output (,'Foo') -NoEnumerate} 
(Test) -is [Array]
```

PowerShell **Windows**

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.17134.858
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.17134.858
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

The issue *doesn't* show up in PowerShell **Core**.
(Both functions return `True`)

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      6.2.0-preview.1
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    6.2.0-preview.1
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.17134
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

There is a note although in the description of [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output?view=powershell-6) cmdlet regarding the `-NoEnumeration` switch:

> **Note**
>
> This switch only works correctly with PowerShell Core 6.2 and newer.
>   On older versions of PowerShell Core, the collection is still
>   enumerated even with use of this switch. The behavior in PowerShell
>   Core 6.2 is consistent with Windows PowerShell.

<sub>(If I read this correct, I understand that the `-NoEnumeration` switch should just work for PowerShell Windows)</sub>

I have reported the issue [here](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/38116117-bug-write-output-inputobject-test-noenumer) at the [Windows PowerShell [UserVoice]](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell) as guided [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Issue-Question&template=Windows_PowerShell.md) by the [PowerShell GitHub Community](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell#-powershell), but it feels like a black hole... (I have reported issues before but hardly see any response).

**Questions:**
Is this indeed a bug or am I missing something?
If it is a bug, is the [Windows PowerShell [UserVoice]](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell) still the correct address to report such an issue?

Comment: Yes, this is a known bug.  No, you can't get it fixed.  It was recently fixed in v6.2

Comment: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5955

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1, thanks for the answer. I came across this issue but couldn't link it to how it appeared to me: using (vs not using) the named `-InputObject` parameter).

Comment: The docs, as quoted in your question, are indeed incorrect as of this writing. Fixing them has been requested in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/5376).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, a **bug in *Windows PowerShell*** (up to v5.1, the last version to be released - since the bug is not security-critical, it is *unlikely to be fixed*) **still causes enumeration when `-NoEnumerate` is passed**, albeit just *one* level.<sup>[1]</sup>

This bug has been **fixed in *PowerShell [Core]* since (at least) v6.2.3**<sup>[2]</sup>

To demonstrate the problem (all commands below now work as expected in PowerShell [Core]):

```sh
WinPS> (Write-Output -NoEnumerate -InputObject 1, 2 | Measure-Object).Count
2 # !! Should be *1*, because a *single array* (with 2 elements) was passed.
```

<sup>Note: It's tempting to omit `Measure-Object` in the command above, but that would distort the results: Using `()`, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--) around a *command* in the context of an expression causes that command's output to be *enumerated*.</sup>

There is a **workaround**: ***omit* `-InputObject`**, i.e to **pass the collection as a *positional* argument**, which, surprisingly, causes the argument to be passed as-is (whereas explicit use of `-InputObject` *enumerates* the argument during parameter binding):

```sh
# POSITIONAL argument binding, without -InputObject
WinPS> (Write-Output -NoEnumerate 1, 2 | Measure-Object).Count
1 # OK
```

Note that this **workaround doesn't work with *pipeline* input**, although this is an **unusual scenario**, given that most commands do *not* output collections *as a whole* to the pipeline (they send their *elements*, *one by one*):

```sh
WinPS> ( , (1, 2) | Write-Output -NoEnumerate | Measure-Object ).Count
2 # !! Should be *1*: the unwrapped outer array contains a *single [array]* element
```

Note: the **outer wrapper array** (**`, (...)`**, using the unary form of `,`, the [array constructor operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#comma-operator-)) is *always* necessary if you want to send a collection *as a whole* through the pipeline using an *expression*.

As such, this single-element wrapper array technique **is a concise and faster alternative to `Write-Output -NoEnumerate` itself**, so, in effect, **`, (1, 2)` *by itself* is the pipeline-based workaround**: it writes the array operand (`1, 2`) *as a whole* to the (success) output stream.

---

[1] ***Not* using `-NoEnumerate` additionally exhibits a related bug in *Windows PowerShell*: *too much* enumeration happens when `-InputObject` is used explicitly**:

One level of recursion is mistakenly applied: An input collection's *elements* are unexpectedly enumerated *as well* (again, PowerShell [Core] now works correctly):

```sh
WinPS> (Write-Output -InputObject 1, (2, 3) | Measure-Object).Count
3 # !! This should be *2*, because the single input array has only 2 elements.
  # !! That the 2nd element is itself an array should not matter.
```

Again, the **workaround** is to ***omit* `-InputObject`**:

```sh
# POSITIONAL argument binding, without -InputObject
WinPS> (Write-Output 1, (2, 3) | Measure-Object).Count
2 # OK
```

---

[2] However, **as of PowerShell (Core) 7.2.2, a bug still exists when you combine

`-NoEnumerate` with a *scalar* argument that is *positionally* bound**:

```sh
PSCore> (Write-Output -NoEnumerate 42).GetType().Name
List`1 #`# !! scalar 42 was unexpectedly wrapped in a *list*
```

The **workaround** is to **use `-InputObject` *explicitly***:

```sh
# OK, thanks to -InputObject
PSCore> (Write-Output -NoEnumerate -InputObject 42).GetType().Name
Int32 # OK
```

This bug - which may never get fixed - is being tracked in [GitHub issue #5122](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5122).