# Powershell Write-Output strange behavior

Tags: powershell

I have a script below that behaves really strangely.

- For the first case I try to return an empty list specifying `-NoEnumarate` flag. But for some reason, the function returns `$null`
- For the second case I do precisely the same as for the first case with the only difference: rather than providing `-InputObject` as a positional parameter, I provide it explicitly.

Why in the first case I get `$null` and in the second case I get the expected result - empty `List[string]`. I'm really confused.

```
# case 1 
function Foo {
    $result = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()
    Write-Output -InputObject $result -NoEnumerate
}

$foo = Foo
if ($foo -is [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]) {
    Write-Host 'Foo'
}

if ($null -eq $foo) {
    Write-Host '$foo is null. Whyyy?'
}


# case 2
function Bar {
    $result = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()
    Write-Output $result -NoEnumerate
}

$bar = Bar
if ($bar -is [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]) {
    Write-Host '$bar is list[string]'
}
```

Comment: When you explicitly specify `-InputObject`, PowerShell attempts to convert the list to the target type `[psobject[]]`. Not specifying `-InputObject` avoids this implicit conversion and thus the problem no longer occurs. See the output from `Trace-Command -Expression { Write-Output ... } -Name * -PSHost`

Comment: Note this behaviour is specific to Windows PowerShell - it's different in PowerShell Core, where the output is ```Foo``` rather than ```$foo is null. Whyyy?```. Here's a potentially related question / answer...  https://stackoverflow.com/a/59989604/3156906

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Could you post your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted